# System.getProperty("java.version") Returns Null

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to compile a class which uses the Processing 3.4 source code. I am getting an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to compile the class which extends `PApplet`.

The `PApplet` class has the following code which I think is the issue

```
public class PApplet implements PConstants {
  /** Full name of the Java version (i.e. 1.5.0_11). */
  static public final String javaVersionName =
    System.getProperty("java.version");

  static public final int javaPlatform;
  static {
    String version = javaVersionName;
    if (javaVersionName.startsWith("1.")) {
      version = version.substring(2);
      javaPlatform = parseInt(version.substring(0, version.indexOf('.')));
    } else {
      // Remove -xxx and .yyy from java.version (@see JEP-223)
      javaPlatform = parseInt(version.replaceAll("-.*","").replaceAll("\\..*",""));
    }
  }
```

I think that the string `javaVersionName` is being set to null or some other weird value which is causing `version.indexOf('.')` to return `-1`.

The stack trace:

```
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 2
    at java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd (String.java:3720)
    at java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1909)
    at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit> (PApplet.java:123)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:830)
```

Somewhere in there it says `at processing.core.PApplet.<clinit> (PApplet.java:123)`. Line 123 in `PApplet.java` is the first line (`public class PApplet ...`) that I posted above.

I suspect it might have something to do with my path and JAVA_HOME system variables. I am using JDK 13 which is added to my path as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin` and the JAVA_HOME variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\`

EDIT: The main function within my class looks like this

```
static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "Demo" };

    if (passedArgs != null) {
        PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
        PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I should also mention that the `PApplet` snippet I posted above is not the actual source that I am using, just something I found online. The actual source I that have is in a `core.jar` folder. I cannot change the source without great difficulty.

Comment: please share a minimal version of your PApplet sublcass (would be good to see how you initialize the applet). Which version of Processing are you using ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/java-9-10-and-macos-issues-with-java-version/

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I added the main function from my class. That code was added when I exported my application from Processing. The reason I wish to compile it myself is so that I can hopefully add it to a web app using Heroku. And the version of processing I am using is 3.4.

Comment: @Oo.oO I am using windows

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether it’s windows or any other system. Java introduced new version format.

Comment: @Oo.oO oh I see. Maybe I'll try to install an older version

Comment: In the post you have info how to deal with the issue. You have to use slightly different way of getting Java version.

Comment: @Oo.oO I cannot change the source code. Or atleast cannot change it without great difficulty

Comment: Either open a bug report with the project that has this code, or use this workaround `System.setProperty("java.version", "...");` to set a version number the buggy code can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are cheating a little bit ;)

The code you have shown is already after the fix for proper handling of Java version since release `9` - this is where you have slightly different version for major release and patched versions.

It looks like your `core.jar` is pre-commit:

https://github.com/processing/processing/commit/b0b2d89228c8bf178f5113a4af25779a14f242e1#diff-29e1de29464981394819a89e38e87288

where handling of `java.version` property was fixed.

So, your sample code should read

```
public class PApplet {
  static public final String javaVersionName =
    System.getProperty("java.version");

  static public final int javaPlatform =
     PApplet.parseInt(PApplet.split(javaVersionName, '.')[1]);


  static public String[] split(String value, char delim) {
    // do this so that the exception occurs inside the user's
    // program, rather than appearing to be a bug inside split()
    if (value == null) return null;
    //return split(what, String.valueOf(delim));  // huh

    char chars[] = value.toCharArray();
    int splitCount = 0; //1;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      if (chars[i] == delim) splitCount++;
    }
    // make sure that there is something in the input string
    //if (chars.length > 0) {
      // if the last char is a delimeter, get rid of it..
      //if (chars[chars.length-1] == delim) splitCount--;
      // on second thought, i don't agree with this, will disable
    //}
    if (splitCount == 0) {
      String splits[] = new String[1];
      splits[0] = value;
      return splits;
    }
    //int pieceCount = splitCount + 1;
    String splits[] = new String[splitCount + 1];
    int splitIndex = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
      if (chars[i] == delim) {
        splits[splitIndex++] =
          new String(chars, startIndex, i-startIndex);
        startIndex = i + 1;
      }
    }
    //if (startIndex != chars.length) {
      splits[splitIndex] =
        new String(chars, startIndex, chars.length-startIndex);
    //}
    return splits;
  }

  static final public int parseInt(String what) {
    return parseInt(what, 0);
  }

  static final public int parseInt(String what, int otherwise) {
    try {
      int offset = what.indexOf('.');
      if (offset == -1) {
        return Integer.parseInt(what);
      } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(what.substring(0, offset));
      }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) { }
    return otherwise;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("Java version: " + javaPlatform);
  }
}
```

and for main

```
public class Main {
  static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "Demo" };

    PApplet.main(appletArgs);
  }
}
```

where you will get your Exception

```
> javac PApplet.java
> javac Main.java
> java -cp . Main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at PApplet.<clinit>(PApplet.java:6)
    ... 1 more
```

if you use the tick suggested in comment, you can get it "fixed"

```
public class Main {
  static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "Demo" };

    System.setProperty("java.version", "1.1.1");

    PApplet.main(appletArgs);
  }
}
```

and you will get your code running

```
> javac PApplet.java
> javac Main.java
> java -cp . Main
Java version: 1
```

So, concluding, why not building it from most recent sources? :)

**Alternative approach - little bit hacky**

Let's say you can't alter neither `Main.java` nor `core.jar`. What you can do here is to cheat `Java` where to look for `PApplet.class`. You can create a dir - let's call it `fix`. Inside `fix` you can compile just one class: `PApplet.java`. And then, you can run the code like this:

```
> java -cp fix:. Main
```

where fix contains your specially crafted version

```
public class PApplet {
  static public final String javaVersionName =
    System.getProperty("java.version");

  static public final int javaPlatform = 1;

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("Java version: " + javaPlatform);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to this:

- the very fact that a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is being thrown within context implies that the `javaVersionName` string is **not** `null`, otherwise, you'd get a `NullPointerException` when `startsWith` is invoked
- The issue here is the assumption that the part of the string after `1.` will have another dot

There are various Java major versions and vendors and the versions change depending on that.

You should simply debug your code and infer what exactly is the value returned there.

As a probably unrelated note, you also want to be cautious if (as the class name suggests), your application is an applet:

> Security consideration: Access to system properties can be restricted
>   by the Security Manager. This is most often an issue in applets, which
>   are prevented from reading some system properties, and from writing
>   any system properties. For more on accessing system properties in
>   applets, refer to System Properties in the Doing More With Java Rich
>   Internet Applications lesson.

Source [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: I can't really debug it since the actual libraries I'm using are already compiled (I tried to recompile everything myself and I need sooooo many other dependencies). Your note on applets is appreciated though.

Comment: @AlexanderDingwall I'm not sure I understand your point about being unable to debug. Can you not just open a socket and set a breakpoint in the source? What does this have to do with the libraries in use and the fact that they are compiled?

Comment: The `PApplet` snippet I posted is not from my actual source that I am using, just something I found online. All I have pertaining to this library is a file called `core.jar` which I add to the classpath when I compile my .java file.

Comment: @AlexanderDingwall I see. Your IDE *should* be able to de-compile that and show you the source though, unless it's obfuscated (in which case it will show you the source, but not in a very useful way :). You should still be able to set a breakpoint where you want and debug this.

Comment: I not actually using an IDE either, haha. Just the command line. I can probably figure out how to decompile them, but I am starting to think Processing 3.4 uses an older version of java, in which case I should probably just install that one. Just need to figure out which one that is.

Comment: @AlexanderDingwall I cannot recommend using an IDE strongly enough. It will make a *lot* of your problems go away. Just trust me on that one: stop everything and set it up now - you may struggle a while at first, but you'll never look back, and that'll provide you invaluable help for all your current and future projects.

Comment: Haha thanks. I might install one since this is turning into a bigger pain in the ass than I was hoping. I do use IDEs for most projects (I wrote this in the Processing IDE) but I am trying to get this project to compile outside of processing so that I can add it to a webapp using Heroku. To do this I need to use Maven and be able to run a specific command from the command line, which is what I am having trouble with.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here:

```
 //supposing Java version 18.9
 version = version.substring(2);
 //now version is equal to "9"
 javaPlatform = parseInt(version.substring(0, version.indexOf('.')));//error! because indexOf('.') return -1 since '.' is not found in variable version
```

So, `indexOf('.')` return -1 and `subString(0,-1)` raise StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Yes, I mention that in my question. I am asking how to fix it.

Comment: @AlexanderDingwall I think is more easy to create in your main  your own static method exact copy of  PAppplet.javaPlatform() , and finally print on console what variable javaVersionName contains

Comment: I am a little confused about what you mean. `javaPlatform` is a `static int` variable

Comment: @AlexanderDingwall sorry I mean PApplet.main method